# Jquery html append after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, append, blogs

Hi I am using the following code example in jquery to generate a html tags into my html file which I will use for a dynamic blog posts in a .ejs file.

**Jquery code:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postChronik').click(function(){
        $( ".demo-container" ).html( "<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>" );
    });
    });
        </script>
```

**HTML**

If I open my html file on my local machine I can't see the generated tag.
If I refreshing my site I can also not see my before generated tag anymore. On serversite I am workin with Node.js.
If I could save the new generated data into my file then it should work but I don't know how can I handle it? Have someone any idea?

Comment: appended elements will be dynamic, so they won't go to file, I think you need some server side techniques to write file.

Comment: Hmm, I am workin with Node.js. I would use Javascript on serversite! I don't know how can I do it yet

Comment: What you will need to do is make and ajax call. Get the html inside the div with class .demo-container and then save this html in the database. When you view the front end, fetch the html and then show it.

Comment: @yunus I have to do it on serversite within node.js with javascript. I am searching an example.